# Google authentication automation for testing

Tags: automated-tests, google-identity

I have an application that uses Google as the Identity Provider. When accessing the application user gets the standard Google username/password popup. Once authenticated by Google, it accesses one of the services in the application with id_token and then this service returns the propriety token that used for further authorization.

My goal is to create an automatic test for such application. Specifically the problem is authentication against Google - until I have id_token. Is there any way to do it automatically, i.e., **without displaying the login and authorization dialogs** - just make several requests and get the **id_token** back eventually? Once I have id_token I know what to do with it against my application. I'd prefer to do this with curl so I can port it to java/javascript/golang or whatever else.

Thanks!